# Django form intergrityerror: foreign key with unique field, unique constraint fails

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When trying to add a second appointment (for the same date) which has a dayplan foreign key using ModelForm and CreateView, unique constraint fails due to DayPlan having 'date' field as unique.

This issue is not present using the django-admin create form.

I tried to remove the unique=True from dayplan.date to see what happens -> every time i add an appointment, even if dayplan.date exist, a new dayplan is created.

the issue seems to be related to these 2 line:

```
    daydate = DayPlan.objects.filter(date=planned_date)
    form.cleaned_data['dayplan'] = daydate
```

The code is here:

```
class DayPlan(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    comment =  models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Planning voor {}'.format(self.date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('organizer_dayplan_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Appointment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    planned_date = models.DateField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    visited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dayplan = models.ForeignKey(DayPlan)

class AppointCreate(CreateView):
    model = Appointment
    form_class = AppointmentForm
    template_name = 'organizer/organizer_appointment_create.html'
    # initial = {'doctor': 'pk', 'comment': 'test',}
    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            "doctor": self.request.GET.get('doctor')
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        planned_date = form.cleaned_data['planned_date']
        try:
            daydate = DayPlan.objects.filter(date=planned_date)
            form.cleaned_data['dayplan'] = daydate
            form.instance.save()


        except:
            daydate = DayPlan.objects.create(date=planned_date)
            form.instance.dayplan = daydate
            form.instance.save()
        return super(AppointCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = {'comment', 'planned_date', 'doctor', 'visited', 'dayplan'}
        widgets = {'visited': forms.HiddenInput(),}
        exclude = {'dayplan',}
```

P.S. i do realize that i don't need to use "form.instance.save()" here. removing them has no effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved

```
daydate, created = DayPlan.objects.get_or_create(date=planned_date)
form.instance.dayplan = DayPlan.objects.get(date=planned_date)
```